# Is there a shortcut to open a blank vertical split window?

Tags: key-bindings, vim-windows

I know there is a shortcut to open a new blank split window horizontally. Namely, `ctrl-w + n`.

But is there a shortcut to do the same thing vertically? More precisely, I want a shortcut for `:vs ene`.

I can't seem to find one inside `help`. Does anyone know if such a shortcut exists or how I would go about mapping it myself considering I need to use `:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special here, if you don't find a shortcut of your liking for a command just create your own with a simple Normal mode mapping. For example:

```
:nmap <Leader>v :vs ene<CR>
```

Assuming your Leader key is backslash then you can just type <kbd>\</kbd> followed quickly by <kbd>v</kbd> and you'll get your vertical split.

You can, of course, choose any key combination you want but using Leader is a good idea as it will not likely conflict with other Vim functionality. (And Leader has other benefits...including the ability to change Leader without changing existing mappings.)

If this is all a bit foreign to you I encourage you to look at Vim help for key mappings (`:h mapping`) and the Leader key (`:h <Leader>`)

Comment: Could map `<C-w>V`, as that's unused.